# How to add a search bar on a map using geo portal extention leaflet

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet

I am trying to update a map that is using leaflet. I want to add a geo search bar.
For that I installed this extension

> geoportal-extensions-leaflet@2.2.2

Now I tried to run this code in the JS.

```
    var searchCtrl = L.geoportalControl.SearchEngine({});
    this.map.addControl(searchCtrl);
```

> TypeError: L.geoportalControl is undefined

L is refering to :

```
    const L = require('leaflet');
```

So now my question is : Does this error means I should do an other "require" for the leaflet geo-portal extensions ? Or does this means that I have installed the extension wrongly or that I did an other mistake ?
Edit : I was misunderstanding how to import the library because I had only tried in online tools like codepen in which imports are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What needs to be done is import both leaflet and geoportal-extensions-leaflet.

After the

```
npm i geoportal-extensions-leaflet
```

The source of the extention is present inside

> node_modules/geoportal-extensions-leaflet

The library should be imported in the JS using :

```
const Gp = require('geoportal-extensions-leaflet');
```

And this code will now works but we should refer to Gp in order to access to the geoportal-extensions-leaflet :

```
var searchCtrl = Gp.geoportalControl.SearchEngine({});
this.map.addControl(searchCtrl);
```